How to use the AD829 Op-Amp? (Weird "auto" output)
I have an AD829 Op-Amp, which I have tested in LTSpice with this circuit/output:

In this simulation I'm amplifying a 6mV signal at 110MHz with the AD829. I have tried this circuit on a breadboard however I only get some weird signal output that the op-amp seems to be generating itself. It looks like this:

So I tried using the inverting input instead but I get the same result. I know it's the op-amp because when I just probe the signal directly from my Colpitts oscillator it shows the correct waveform. This is what my circuit looks like:
(See Edits for full setup)

(yellow is signal from oscillator. The resistors are the same as in the LTSpice. The cap is 10uF.)
What am I doing wrong?
Edit:
After adding a 0.1uF capacitor across pin 4 & 7:

The entire setup:


@All - Although well-intentioned, the long comment chain has exceeded what is reasonable for comments. Therefore comments so far have been moved to chat & should be continued there (see link in the comment below). || As this bulk moving of comments to chat can only be done once per question, any further comments posted here may be deleted without notice. Keep it in chat now, please! || Any improvement / clarification to the question decided during the chat, should be made via an [edit], not as a comment. When someone has enough information to post an answer, please answer it as usual. TY

Comments have been moved to this chatroom and discussion should be continued there. Please do not continue the discussion in comments here.

From the chat-room discussion, it seems this question is part of a larger project, and I would advise reviewing all aspects of your project plan with people competent with basic RF comms technology.
That said, this answer is focused on suggestions for a simple & effective broad-band linear amplifier that can boost a signal of 6mVp-p at 110MHz with a gain of between 10 to 50 (exact value will depend on various tweaks to the material presented below).  This gain should be sufficient to boost up the signal to about 300mVp-p, which can then be an input to further down-stream processing by signal processing stages that are as-yet unknown and undefined.
You can get good bandwidth (DC to 300MHz) and OK gain (~10 to 20) from commonly available small-signal BJTs using the simple two-transistor circuit known as the "feedback pair" or "shunt-series feedback pair".  Several of these amplifiers can then be connected in series to increase gain, however this comes with a corresponding reduction in bandwidth.  Of course, much greater bandwidth and gain is possible if you use RF transistors, however, these may be more difficult to source.
Reference: Horowitz & Hill, "The Art of Electronics", 2nd edition. Section 13.07, page 872.



A more complex differential amplifier (like an op-amp) with bandwidth out to 200MHz is presented in Section 13.05 page 869, Figure 13.10.  This uses several high-speed techniques to get the most out of relatively modest-speed transistors (techniques such as input buffering, cascoding, and output buffering).


Note: Beware, this section seems to have been removed from the subsequent 3rd edition. The 2nd edition is available here:
https://pearl-hifi.com/06_Lit_Archive/02_PEARL_Arch/Vol_16/Sec_51/4420_The_Art_of_Electronics.pdf
Band-pass LC filters for RF:
If you want to explore using passive components (Cs, Ls) to create a band-pass filter (as part of a radio detector, for example), then this may be a good starting point:
How to properly design LC bandpass filters?
